# Increasing width of Reader on FME Desktop?

Tags: fme-form

I have a reader whose attribute names are so long that I can´t read them in the workbench.

Is there anyway to increase the size of the reader element?

[image]

With the mouseover the attributes can be read, but I need to scan them visually quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have FME 2015, you can just drag the whole feature type wider.

[See an animated gif of resizing here](https://vine.co/v/Opg36VAqUd0)